# Add sessionid as header in POST Request with framework7 using ajax request

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I need sessionid of user for server side authentication. So need to post Sessionid in header of every request where ever essential. I am using following to post sessionId in header but something wrong is happened.

```
apiservice.getProfileDetails = function(data, callback){
// $.cookie("sessionid", $.jStorage.get("sessionKey"));
document.cookie = "sessionid=" +$.jStorage.get("sessionKey");
console.log(document.cookie);
var requestEnvelope = {
    url: apiservice.baseUrl + '/get/my/information/?callback='+callback,
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    // beforeSend : function(xhr) { var cookie = credentials["COOKIE"]; console.info( "adding cookie: "+ $.jStorage.get("sessionKey") ); xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', $.jStorage.get("sessionKey")); },
    beforeSend: function (request)
            {
            request.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "sessionid=" +$.jStorage.get("sessionKey"));
            },
    // setCookies: $.jStorage.get("sessionKey"), 
    // headers: {"sessionid": $.jStorage.get("sessionKey")},
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    complete: function(res){
            ux.getProfileDetails(res.responseText);
    }
   }
    $.ajax(requestEnvelope);
};
```

Error occurred is `jquery.min.js:4 Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"`

Also tried to set cookies in header

```
headers: {"sessionid": $.jStorage.get("sessionKey")},
```

but same error, any solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in a project with framework7 and I find 2 ways using $$ of framework7

1) set this to be execute before every ajax.

```
var $$ = Dom7;

$$(document).on('ajaxStart', function(e){
   var xhr = e.detail.xhr;
   xhr.setRequestHeader('token', 'value');
});
```

2) https://framework7.io/docs/dom.html

see headers parameter in ajax.